# Android/Java: Starting activity from class method

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I'm trying to start a new activity from a non-activity class.

From the main menu:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;


public class Menu extends Activity {


    Button start, options;
    GameLoop Game = new GameLoop();

    @Override

    public void onCreate(Bundle mainStart) {
        super.onCreate(mainStart);
        setContentView(R.layout.menu);

    start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bStart);

    options = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bOptions);

    start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent openStart = new Intent(Menu.this, Game.class);
            startActivity(openStart);

        }
    });

    options.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Context mContext = null; //Error called for mContext to be initialized so just tried setting to null. This is most likely the error cause it would make more sense for it to be equal to "getContext()" or something like that
            Game.Start(mContext);//Here
        }
    });

    }

}
```

I'm trying to open an activity from the Game.Start() method.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

public class GameLoop extends Menu{
    boolean hello = false;

    public void Start(Context sContext){
        Intent openOptions = new Intent(sContext, Options.class);
        startActivity(openOptions);

    }

}
```

I'm not sure if using context would be the right way of going about this but I figured it was worth a try. Im entirely new to java and android so I'm pretty much lost on where to go next. Any help in what direction to take would be throughly appreciated.

Comment: first make the start method static in your Game class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Activity extends Context, so you can just use `this` when inside Activity.

```
Game.Start(Menu.this);
```

I use `Menu.this` because you are inside inner anonymous class (View.OnClickListener) where `this` refers to this inner class.

Comment: That makes perfect sense but it still crashes on load?

Comment: Your `GameLoop` extends `Menu`, You can not instantiate it with `new`.

Comment: Oh gotcha. I changed that to "GameLoop Game;" and now it crashes on button press..

Comment: Why do you need `GameLoop` to extend `Menu`? Get rif of `extend Menu`. And bring back the `new`.

Comment: I just needed to in some way extend 'Activity' to be able to use 'startActivity()' (at least I think I need to). I changed it to 'public class GameLoop extends Activity' but same problem with the crashing on button press.

Comment: Why? Why? Just get rid if it - `GameLoop` shouldn't extend anything. Do you use it for some other purpose? If not, you do not need it in the first place. Just use `startActivity()` directly in `Menu` activity.

Comment: Without extending 'Activity' in some way startActivity() is unknown. Unless theres a way around it I honestly thought thats just what you have to do :/

Comment: Ahh, yes. Use `sContext.startActivity(openOptions)`

Answer (score 0):

**Do you added the new activities to the androidmanifest.xml?**